# Int/Float weighted average datetime in DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, floating-point, int

I am trying to figure out the way to take `int` or `float` weighted average of `datetime` fields. I am thinking on the lines of converting `datetime` to `int` and then do the maths and then convert back to `datetime`. But not sure how to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

I should have been more clear here. The actual problem is to do something like this

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Qty': {0: 100, 1: 3232, 2: 4232, 3: 4322, 4: 666, 5: 98}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14:05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'},'Id':{0:'abc',1:'abc',2:'bcd',3:'bcd',4:'abc',5:'bcd'}})
>>> df1
         Date   Id   Qty     StartTime
0  2016-10-11  abc   100  08:00:00.241
1  2016-10-11  abc  3232  08:00:00.243
2  2016-10-11  bcd  4232  12:34:23.563
3  2016-10-11  bcd  4322  08:14:05.908
4  2016-10-11  abc   666  18:54:50.100
5  2016-10-11  bcd    98  10:08:36.657
>>> df1['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] + ' ' + df1['StartTime'])
>>> df1['StartTime'][0]
Timestamp('2016-10-11 08:00:00.241000')
```

Now I am trying to groupby `Id` and take `Qty` weighted `StartTime`. Please note that `StartTime` has microsecond component as well.
The following does not seem to work, even though each item of `StartTime` column is `Timestamp`:

```
>>> (df1.groupby['Id']).apply(lambda x:np.average(x['StartTime'], weights=x['Qty']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Some code would help demonstrate your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to give you an integer that can be used to average multiple `datetime` values.

```
def avg_date(lst):
    epoch = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    seconds_per_day = 3600 * 24
    avg = sum((d - epoch).total_seconds() for d in lst) / len(lst)
    return epoch + datetime.timedelta(avg // seconds_per_day, avg % seconds_per_day)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mark. However I need to include microseconds. Also, earlier I wasn't explicit enough in my question that I need to apply this to a `DataFrame` column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timestamp

```
import datetime 
dt1 = datetime.datetime.now()
dt2 = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1)
timestamp1 = dt1.timestamp()
timestamp2 = dt2.timestamp()
timestamp_avg = (timestamp2+timestamp1)/2
dt_avg = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_avg)
print(dt_avg)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @SergeyLebedev. I wasn't explicit enough in my question earlier that I need to apply this to a `DataFrame` column. Though column is `TimeStamp` this does not seem to work.